# new File("/").listFiles() return null on Android 7.0 device

Tags: file, permissions, android-7.0-nougat

as description of the tiltle.

```
File[] files = new File("/").listFiles();
```

i will get the file array of root directory under android 7.0
then null on android 7.0 device.

Comment: Since you don't necessarily have read access to the root directory, this does not surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

go setting-apps-your app-Permissions-All Permissions and enadble read the content of your Storage[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bML80.jpg)